# How to get scrollTop of page just after page onload event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload, scrolltop, onscroll

I know how to get the `scrollTop` of a page, I use this simple JS function (code copied around):

```
function GetScrolledTop() 
{
   //I never work in IE quirkmode, I always use DOCTYPE as 1st line, so I don't need to test for document.body.scrollTop
   return self['pageYOffset'] || document.documentElement.scrollTop; 
}
```

This works and my problem is the following: I tried to add it in the page onload event

```
<body onload="alert(GetScrolledTop());">
```

On page load I get ZERO (which make sense), but the problem is that I get ZERO **even if I scroll the page and then reload it without touching the scrollbar.**

It seems like the browser does:

1. loads page
2. calls my `GetScrolledTop()` (so obviously shows ZERO)
3. then scrolls the page to where it was before.

Do you know how to get the `scolledTop` after the step 3?
I mean how to get the `scrolledTop` **AFTER the browser scrolled the page?**
(maybe without using a timer)

Comment: From a user interface/experience point of view, it is not a really good idea to take over a native functionnality of the browser to help in navigation by scrolling back to the top of the page.

Comment: @bgy: there was no mention of taking over functionality, only getting the current scroll position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not without using a timer.  But you might be able to use a timer with a 0ms delay, which would execute the function when the thread becomes idle, whilst still appearing to be instant:

```
<body onload="window.setTimeout(function () { alert(GetScrolledTop()); } , 0);">
```

**EDIT** - Thought it might also be worth mentioning that [most browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/index.html#t021) support the [`onscroll`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/tests/scroll.html) event, which should fire after the window scrolls.

Comment: +1 the window.setTimeout trick works in all browser except IE7 and IE8 (didn't try IE6). Using the onscroll event works everywhere.